# How to make changes in .bash_profile permanent?

Tags: command-line

I added the following to my `.bash_profile`

```
alias lr='ls -hartl'
alias q='grep -i'
alias get='curl -OL'
```

then

```
source .bash_profile
```

the aliases worked as expected.

But if I close the shell and open it again (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) I have to `source .bash_profile` again for the changes to be implemented.

Is there a way to make this permanent so I don't have to `source .bash_profile` every time I open a new shell?

Comment: Did you try logging out and in again or rebooting?

Comment: See:  https://www.stefaanlippens.net/bashrc_and_others/  the `.bash_profile` is loaded when it is a login shell, but since you are not creating a login shell at the time of opening a new terminal it is not called each time.  If you added the lines to the `.bashrc` file it would be called each time.  If you keep the lines in the `.bash_profile` then you would need to log out and log back in for the changes to be permanent.

Comment: @dessert yes. rebooting doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as pointed out in the following link (posted by @Terrance) 
https://www.stefaanlippens.net/bashrc_and_others/

The Answer is to add the info into `.bashrc` not `.bash_profile`

Comment: My rule of thumb is: anything that is specifically for interactive use (aliases, functions, the prompt, etc) goes in .bashrc (or into files that the .bashrc sources), and things that not for interactive use (env vars) goes in the .profile

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your gnome-terminal profile to open new tabs as login sessions,  so that .bash_profile gets re-read.